# Meteor & iron-router: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have made simple page without routing and it work's nice, but after adding routing i'm have this error in my browser console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

My router.js:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
});
```

My layout.html:

```
<tempate name = "layout">
<html>
<head>
... includes here
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
  {{ >yield }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
</template>
```

My index.html:

```
<template name="index">
<input type="checkbox" name="choiceMe" class="typeChoice" checked>

<script>
  var options = {
    onText: "ON",
    offText: "OFF",
  };
  $("[name='choiceMe']").bootstrapSwitch(options);
</script>
</template>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: what have you tried so far in terms of diagnosis? Where and when do you load the scrip that provides `bootstrapSwitch`? does the page still render? Also, the head doesn't belong in the template (please read the documentation http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)

Comment: Thank you, fixed by moving <head> outside of template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `head` should not be included in templates.

Change `layout.html` to:

```
<head>
... includes here
</head>

<tempate name = "layout">
 <div class="container"> 
   {{ >yield }}
 </div>
</template>
```